# Ubuntu 12.10 and Prolong SSD life

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I will be installing Ubuntu 12.10 on a SSD as a dual boot with Windows 7. I also have a HDD that will be used as a data drive.

I was thinking of having:

- / on SSD
- /home on HDD
- swap on HDD

Is there any other folders that I could move to it own partition? How much space would I need for the different partitions?

Is there any other tips anyone can give for prolonging the life of the SSD?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prolong SSD life

**Enable TRIM**

Back up fstab first in case something wrong happen.

```
# cp /etc/fstab ~/fstab.bk
```

Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

**Disable hibernation**

```
# nano /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

Look for

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

Change from “yes” to “no”, there are two, one for hibernation, and another one for suspend. If you have to disable them both, make sure to replace them both from yes to no.

```
<allow_active>no</allow_active>
```

**Tmpfs**

Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the line to the end of fstab file

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

If logs aren’t important for you (laptop or desktop), you can also mount /var/log to tmpfs. Add the line to the end of fstab file

```
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=0755 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of guides specifically for Linux and SSDs. Search for: *SSD tuning linux* (or similar). They don't necessarily have to be for Ubuntu. I think I got a number of steps from the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives).

The main thing is to set AHCI mode in the bios, and after installation edit `/etc/fstab` to add "noatime,nodiratime,discard" options for the SSD partitions.

In my system I also included `/tmp` on the HDD, just because who knows what (or how often) stuff will be written there.